# Regex - only allow a space or nothing after a match

Tags: c#, regex

Hi I'm nearly new with this of Regex... so, maybe my problem it's easy but I can't find a solution!

I'm writing a regex pattern that looks into the user's writing and paint with another color the matches that is founded.
I want for example to paint with another color, if the user write something like this:

```
foo()
```

the thing is that I DON'T want to paint that if the user writes something else after that, I mean if the user write only

```
"foo()" (or "foo() ")
```

then it's fine, I want to paint it, but if the user write

```
"foo()d"
```

I don't want to paint that because is now well written for me.

I already wrote the regex pattern that match the "foo()" (or also with a dot in the middle, like "foo.foo()"), but I´m facing with that problem. 
I need to add something to my pattern that allow only a space, or nothing (if the user write something else after the ")" I don't want to match it.)
This is my pattern:

```
[a-z]*\.?[a-z]*\(("[^"\r\n]*"|[-]?\b\d+[\.]?\d*\b)?\)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking.  Are there any characters after this?  If not, you can just end your regex with `\s?$`.

Comment: right, this will not work because I want to let the user to continue writing...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

David Brabant is close, but I think you actually want to try ending your regular expression with `(?!\S)` - this will mean you'll match anything not followed by a non-whitespace character.  If you just want to match on spaces rather than whitespace, use `(?![^ ])`.

Comment: Since you are new to Regex, you may also not know about the ^ and $ symbols. They are line anchors. For example, if your regex was "^foo()[ ]?$" it would match "foo()" and "foo() " ONLY for the entire line.

Answer (score 6):

Use negative look ahead:

```
(\w+)(\.*)(\(\))+(\s)*(?!.)
```

The important part for you in the regex above is: (\s)*(?!.)

(\s)* : followed by 0 or more white spaces
(?!.) : and no other character

Comment: @gezequiel: See my previous comment. There's one little tweak you need to make to this.

Comment: yea... but it will not work if you start writing something else after this regex.
I mean, I want the user can write something like this:
something() and somethingElse()
and paint the two sentences

Answer (score 1):

```
[a-z]*\.?[a-z]*\(("[^"\r\n]*"|[-]?\b\d+[\.]?\d*\b)?\)[ ]?
```

Adding a `[ ]?` should do it. `?` is used for `1` or `0`, `[ ]` will only match space.

Also, `[\s]?` would work for all types of whitespace (tabs included).

Comment: This won't work, as if the next character isn't white space, it'll match the space zero times.  I think gezequiel wants to fail if he matches `\S`, i.e. a non-whitespace character.

Comment: Ah thanks Ade, should have read the question more thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

could you try to add:

\s*% ?

\s* : zero or more spaces

% means: end of string

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you're looking for according to my regex tester:

```
[a-z]*\.?[a-z]*\(("[^"\r\n]*"|[-]?\b\d+[\.]?\d*\b)?\)([ ]?)(?!.)
```

If you want to allow for more than one space, use this:

```
[a-z]*\.?[a-z]*\(("[^"\r\n]*"|[-]?\b\d+[\.]?\d*\b)?\)([ ]*)(?!.)
```